# Access 2010 VBA and filtering

Tags: vba, filter, public

Good Day,

I need some assistance please. I am rebuilding a third party Access database after it's catastrophic failure and the failure of the 3rd party developer to fix his mess. I am an avid Access Developer and know my way around an Access Database well. I am not a super VBA coder, but I can do more than my bit in VBA as well as a few other languages.

Currently, I have a database test bed with a login form that stores 3 values as public variables (gstrLevel as String, gstrUser as String, gintID as Integer). I am able to set my own "permissions" with ease in that once they login I can use the values to control the switchboard etc.

My problem now is the following. We have people recording prospective client interactions and interviews. As part of the process, every time they make contact, they record this into the database and in the process a "followup date" is created. This works like a charm. What I now need to do is warm the users if these followup dates are close or have passed so that prompt action can be taken lest we lose a prospective client.

I have a query that takes the prospective table information, and the notes table information (where the followup date is stored) and then filters the dates correctly. This in turn has been used to create a continues form to display the records that need followup soon. What I cannot seem to do is to get it to only show the logged in users followup records.

I should note that the user/agent field is a lookup field in the prospective table, and thus also creates a combo box in the Followup form. I can lock the form from changes etc, but I can't seem to get it to only display the relevant user/agent details.

I have tried:

```
DoCmd.ApplyFilter
Me.Filter
Me.FilterOn = True
DLookup as criteria
Using my public variables directly as query criteria
And a few other weird combinations with no success.
```

My problem, I believe, is the fact that the user/agent is a lookup field, and I am not sure how to filter based on that fact. If I use the gstrUser variable directly I get a type mismatch and if I use gintID directly it shows nothing.

Any ideas or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a Users table, with a numeric Primary Key (PK), while your gstrUser stores the userName.
So in the source of your Followup form, just add the Users table (joined to the Prospective table on UserId) and apply the filter on the userName field in the Users table (or whatever it's called that matches the contents of gstrUser).